# Karma Browserify bundle error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, browserify, karma-jasmine, vue.js

Trying to get a combination of `vue.js`, `Karma`, and `browserify` to play nicely for unit-testing. Currently I believe that my `browserify` process is not working correctly. When the test parses my file, it reports back with an error on line 1:

```
17 07 2016 00:40:44.501:ERROR [framework.browserify]: bundle error

./../../../tests/js/site/Validator.spec.js:1
import Validator from './mixins/Validator.js'
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

The key section of my `karma.conf.js` file looks like the following:

```
preprocessors: {
    './../../../tests/js/**/*.js': ['browserify']
},

browserify: {
    debug: true, // debug=true to generate source maps
    transform: [ ['vueify', {'presets' : ['es2015']}] ]
},
```

I've been digging and it sounds like this is due to `browserify` not handling `ES6` very well and it requires presets for `babel` to do it's thing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slight tweak of my `browserify` section in `karma.conf.js` seemed to do the trick. It works now after changing it to the following:

```
browserify: {
    debug: true,
    transform: [ ['babelify', {presets: ["es2015"]}] ],
},
```